# Listing dataframes based on the names of the dataframes (Calling dataframes by name)

Tags: r, dataframe

Lets say I have 5 dataframes and I want to create a list of them based on their name (just like we can filter columns and rows based on name or similarities to a word).

Example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Y = rnorm(15), Z = rnorm(15))
df2 <- data.frame(Y = rnorm(15), Z = rnorm(15))
df3 <- data.frame(Y = rnorm(15), Z = rnorm(15))

specialdf1 <- data.frame(Y = rnorm(15), Z = rnorm(15))
specialdf2 <- data.frame(Y = rnorm(15), Z = rnorm(15))
specialdf3 <- data.frame(Y = rnorm(15), Z = rnorm(15))

speciallist <- list(specialdf1, specialdf2, specialdf3)
```

Instead of doing this by hand I want to call the dataframes by something they have in their name (e.g. "special") AND not be limited to e.g. 3 dataframes (since I would not know how many dataframes will be there in actuality). How would I do this?

Comment: Try `mget(ls(pattern = 'specialdf[0-9]+'))`

Comment: adding to what @Sotos have:  `mget(ls(pattern = 'special'), mode = 'list')`

Comment: Good thinking @Onyambu. Eventhough `list` is the default, it is still useful to show

Comment: @Sotos no. list is not the default. I believe `any` is the default. meaning if you have a character/string called special123char, it will be captured. But OP only needs dataframes

Comment: True. I was referring to the object (being df)

Comment: Hi thank you both, for some reason it only accepts it if I write it until at least the last underscore in the case of a long name with multiple underscores, e.g.:         ```plots_list <- mget(ls(pattern = 'specialdf_NM_[0-20]+'))```. Can someone answer it so I can write it as solved / what should I do?

Comment: I m sure this is a duplicated question so I will look for it and close this one. No worries, you dont need to do anything :)

Comment: Thank you, I'm probably a bit too new to R to know how to look more specific for some questions (I did try :))